# For a DynamoDB eventually consistent query are there any read ordering guarantees?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, eventual-consistency

Consider a scenario where I have a writer process inserting documents into a DynamoDB table. The documents all have the **same partition key** but different sort keys. The writer inserts document A, B, C, D, E one after the other in that order.

Now another reader process does an **eventually consistent** query to read the documents that have just been inserted. I understand with eventual consistency there is no guarantee the reader will immediately see all the documents inserted.

My question is if it is possible for the reader to ever see documents arriving out-of-order from the order they were written? For example could the query return documents A, B, E but not C and D even though they were inserted before E. Remember all documents have the same partition key.

Comment: I don't think the fact that they have the same partition key would make a difference here. If your app relies on this ordering, I would recommend opening a support case. It's probably not a good idea to take our words for this undocumented piece.

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc that is some wise advice. I wish the documentation was better on these sort of details. For now I'm going to assume we can't rely on this.